# How to pass the output of a bash command to Github Action parameter

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have a workflow where after a push to master I want to create a release and upload an asset to it.

I'm using `actions/create-release@v1` and `actions/upload-release-asset@v1`.

I would like to pass the outputs of a bash commands to the action parameters. However I found out the syntax of "$(command)" does not work.

How can I pass the output of a bash command to an action's parameter.

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
- name: Create Release
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.token }}
  with:
    tag_name: $(cat projectFile | grep -Po '(?<=Version>).*(?=</Version>)')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This answer will not work as GitHub as disabled this syntax for security reasons. You should use [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) instead.

I would create an environment variable based of your command output:

```
- name: Retrieve version
  run: |
    echo ::set-env name=TAG_NAME::$(cat projectFile | grep -Po '(?<=Version>).*(?=</Version>)')
```

And then access it like the following:

```
- name: Create Release
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.token }}
  with:
    tag_name: ${{ env.TAG_NAME }}
```

Comment: Wait, there's one problem, I also want to get the release notes, which have newlines in them and I use `cat projectFile | grep -Pzo '(?<=PackageReleaseNotes>)(.|\n)*(?=</PackageReleaseNotes>)'`, however only the first line gets set in the variable.

Comment: The following link should help you to handle multilines: (https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/set-output-Truncates-Multiline-Strings/m-p/52466#M8527)

You would have something like:
`run: |
     RELEASE_NOTES="$(grep -Pzo '(?<=PackageReleaseNotes>)(.|\n)*(?=</PackageReleaseNotes>)' projectFile)"
     RELEASE_NOTES="${RELEASE_NOTES//'%'/'%25'}"
     RELEASE_NOTES="${RELEASE_NOTES//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
     RELEASE_NOTES="${RELEASE_NOTES//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
     echo "::set-env name=RELEASE_NOTES::$RELEASE_NOTES"`

Comment: Note ::set-env is now deprecated - https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files

Answer (score 67):

**Update: `set-output` is being deprecated as well "Starting 1st June 2023 workflows using save-state or set-output commands via stdout will fail with an error."**

Now that `set-env` is deprecated and `set-output` is soon to be deprecated, you can use `GITHUB_OUTPUT` environment files: to accomplish the same thing in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61258467/4582374)

```
- name: Retrieve version
  run: |
    echo "TAG_NAME=$(cat projectFile | grep -Po '(?<=Version>).*(?=</Version>)')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: version
```

```
- name: Create Release
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.token }}
  with:
    tag_name: ${{ steps.version.outputs.TAG_NAME }}
```

References:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files

[How to save the output of a bash command to output parameter in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605228/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-bash-command-to-output-parameter-in-github-actions?noredirect=1#comment116006635_65605228)

Comment: GitHub is also deprecating set-output - see https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/ instead use `echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` where in the example above `{name}` would be `TAG_NAME` and the `{value}` would be the `$(...` command output

Comment: The deprecation has been postponed as there is still significant use of `save-state` and `set-output` - ref https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 37):

Use [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files)

```
steps:
  - name: Set the value
    id: step_one
    run: |
        echo "FOO=$(git status)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
        echo "${{ env.FOO }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this example as I couldn't see any useful example code in the linked section in the docs.

Comment: this is now (Oct. 2022) the preferred way as GitHub is deprecating both `set-env` and `set-output`, see https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/